Gitsigns without lua
I'm new and I've been working with nvim without lua and everything is fine, I want to install the gitsigns plugin but all tutorial seems to use lua, I tried just adding Plug 'lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim' to my init.vim and it installs but the plugin doesn't work; is it just not possible? or am I doing something wrong? this is my init.vim btw:
set number
set mouse
syntax enable
set showcmd
set encoding=utf-8
set showmatch
set ruler
set smartcase

call plug#begin()
" The default plugin directory will be as follows:
"   - Vim (Linux/macOS): '~/.vim/plugged'
"   - Vim (Windows): '~/vimfiles/plugged'
"   - Neovim (Linux/macOS/Windows): stdpath('data') . '/plugged'
" You can specify a custom plugin directory by passing it as the argument
"   - e.g. `call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')`
"   - Avoid using standard Vim directory names like 'plugin'

" Make sure you use single quotes
Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'

Plug 'junegunn/seoul256.vim'

Plug 'fatih/vim-go'

Plug 'nsf/gocode'

" Tree
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'

Plug 'tpope/vim-fireplace', { 'for': 'clojure' }

" preview markdown files
Plug 'iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim', { 'do': 'cd app && npx --yes yarn install' }

" status bar
Plug 'feline-nvim/feline.nvim'

" syntax
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'

" typing
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plug 'alvan/vim-closetag'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'

" move panels

" autocomplete
Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}

" IDE
Plug 'editorconfig/editorconfig-vim'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'yggdroot/indentLine'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'

" git
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Plug 'lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim', { 'current_line_blame' : 'true' }

call plug#end()

" nmaping
:nnoremap <C-t> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
:nnoremap <C-f> :FZF<CR>
" Make <CR> to accept selected completion item or notify coc.nvim to format
" <C-g>u breaks current undo, please make your own choice.
inoremap <silent><expr> <CR> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm()
                             \: "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"

Tried :PlugInstall Function (working fine) but the expected highlights won't show
Edit: I decided to install a few plugins and organize my nvim configuration folder separated by modules, before I knew it, it miraculously started working.

Use the plugin’s issue tracker.

Add following in your init.vim:
lua <<EOF
require('gitsigns').setup()
EOF


It's not possible to use the gitsigns.nvim plugin without Lua. This plugin uses only Lua, not Vimscript => see https://github.com/lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim/blob/main/lua/gitsigns.lua
IMHO, it's a bad idea to use Neovim WITHOUT Lua. If you want to use only plugins in Vimscript, use Vim instead.
